# Should I update my current ionic 3 app to ionic 5 and capacitor or should I move to capacitor from cordova?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I currently have 4 applications loaded with Cordova plugin and functioning well. But as I know ionic is releasing updates quite frequently so should I keep my ionic 3 application to ionic 3 and update it to the capacitor or should I update both ionic and Cordova?

Comment: Cordova getting deprecated and all the new updates are based on capacitor only.  It's for ionic, electron js and so on. better move ahead with capacitor.

Comment: @ManojkumarMuthukumar Yes the new updates are based on capacitor only but I have one doubt that let say I have few Cordova plugin which is not available in capacitor so for those plugins what can be done?

Comment: There is always a alternate solution. If you have existing project with cordova integrated. It's very complicate to migrate first prepare all alternate solutions if everything available you can move forward to capacitor.

Comment: There are some Plugins which are not available on capacitor. And in My Personal Experience Capacitor is having performance Issues right now. I made 2, 3 apps on capacitor all have Performance Issues even after optimizing everything. I suggest you to upgrade to ionic 5 with Cordova. and When capacitor gets stable and have all plugins available then you can mode to it.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib umm as the capacitor is quite new so it will take time to get stable. But the update from ionic 3 to 5 is also quite big. is there any tool or way that can help me to migrate easily and faster?

Comment: Never done migration like this. But I think there are breaking changes so you should do it manually. Specially HTML elements and CSS. You can pretty much Use your TS code.

Comment: Cordova has the benefit of being mature, but with that comes the issue of old, deprecated libraries. You will regularly find libraries which haven't been updated in 8+ years which are no longer compatible with modern operating systems. Capacitor is the way forward, even if it's early in it's life by comparison. Go with Capacitor is my advice.